# What Slack scopes are needed for adding a bot to private channels using conversations.join API method?

Tags: slack-api, conversation-scope

I'm using JS [Bolt SDK](https://api.slack.com/tools/bolt) to add my bot to private channels programatically. According to Slack [docs](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.join) for `conversation.join` , the bot should have certain scopes for the call to success. I had no problem with public channels by adding the scope `channel:join` .

However, I can't manage to do the same for private channels and Bolt throws the error **channel not found**, which I'm almost sure it's due to missing scopes (I had the same problem in the past when trying to post messages to private channels without the required scope)

What are the required scopes to add a bot to private channels? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Private channels are "invite only", hence they can't be joined "by choice" using 'conversation.join' api.

 A member of private channel will have to add the bot to the channel manually.